Rollup.js ES bundle failing to resolve react-icons/io5 dependency
I'm working on creating an NPM package (for a private company-specific NPM registry) containing a single React component and from searching online on how to do this, I decided to use Rollup.js to bundle my package before publishing. I've been able to use rollup to build an ES bundle (chosen because I thought it's the convention so that it can use import/export syntax just like any other component library), publish it to my registry, and install it in a client React application. When I try to run the app, though, it shows this error:
ERROR in ./node_modules/@<MY ORG>/<MY PACKAGE>/dist/bundle.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-icons/io5' in 'app/node_modules/@<MY ORG>/<MY PACKAGE>/dist'
Did you mean 'index.esm.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request 'react-icons/io5' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified (probably because the origin is strict ES module, e.g. a module with JS mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"'.
...
Add the extension to the request.
...

There's a ton of output here but the simple fix it suggested of adding the extension in my import didn't work with some other error message. I don't want to have to take that route anyway since I've seen other posts where people import installed NPM packages without it. I thought that'd enter the index.js file in the directory they import from, but I'm very new to all of this.
My package.json contains (here's what I think is relevant):
"type": "module", // Needed because I'm making an ES bundle? I don't know
"source": "src/index.js",
"devDependencies": {    
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^26.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^6.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^5.0.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-url": "^8.0.2",
    "@semantic-release/gitlab": "^13.2.1",
    "@semantic-release/npm": "^12.0.1",
    "rollup": "^4.21.3",
    "rollup-plugin-delete": "^2.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.5",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-serve": "^1.1.1",
    "semantic-release": "^24.1.1"
}

My rollup.config.js:
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import url from '@rollup/plugin-url';
import del from 'rollup-plugin-delete';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
 

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/bundle.js',
    format: 'esm',
    sourcemap: true,
    exports: 'default',
  },

  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }),
    commonjs(),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
      babelHelpers: 'bundled'
    }),
    external(),
    del({ targets: ['dist/*'] }),
    json(),
    postcss(),
    url()
  ],
};

Can someone assist? I'm sorry I can't give more information, but this is for a work project and I don't know what I can give out. Feel free to let me know what specific information would help.
